# How to Add a editbox and a button in mfc sdi main window?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, user-interface, button, mfc

I am making a Messanger application in `MFC`. So , I am using  a MFC SDI .

As my requirement, I have to add two `editbox` and one `button` for signIn in the main window of application. I can do this by `dialog box` easily but I have to add these in view of main window. I read about doc/view `architecture` , but still facing the same problem.

I am new to `UI` and `MFC` both. Please help me out in adding these elements in the view of main window.

Comment: Hello Jerry Coffin..Thanks for the Answer . It solve my problem up to a great extent. But I need further assistance. Once after doing a successful login in the main form, I will have to refresh the window , remove all the buttons and edit boxes, and have to put new vie of online clients lists. Still I have to understand view/doc architecture for that in deep???

Comment: After the user has logged in you can switch to a different view. See "Adding Multiple Views to a Single Document" in MSDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derive your view from [`CFormView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/353dcby6.aspx). This hosts controls defined in a dialog resource, so you can just draw the dialog in the normal dialog editor, then tell your CFormView-derived view to use that, and it'll handle all the usual dialog-like things for you.

Oh, and just like when those controls are a normal dialog, you can also associate the controls with variables if you want.

If you really want to, you *can* write code to directly create and position your controls in a class derived directly from `CView` instead. As a general rule, I'd prefer to use a `CFormView` though--it's intended for this specific purpose, so unless you have a reason to do otherwise, it's probably better to use what it provides than duplicate roughly the same functionality yourself.

Assuming you use the AppWizard for your initial application creation, you can select the base class in the last frame:

[image]

Once you've selected that and create the application, if you look in the resource view, you'll find two dialog templates: one is for the About box, the other for your View.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the CFormView class. It's a view class that uses a dialog resource. So, you can use the resource editor to drop controls like buttons and edit boxes on top of a view.